# set separator ';' in write.csv

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I have the following code:

```
myTable[i,] = strsplit(line, split=";")[[1]]
write.csv(myTable[-1,], file="episodes_cleared.csv", sep=";", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

Unfortunately, the separator still is ',':

```
iEpisodeId,iPatientId,sTitle,sICPc,dStart,dEnd,bProblem
```

Running the code gives me:

Warning messages:

```
1: In write.csv(myTable[-1, ], file = "episodes_cleared.csv", sep = ";",  : attempt to set 'sep' ignored
2: In write.csv(myTable[-1, ], file = "episodes_cleared.csv", sep = ";",  :
```

attempt to set 'sep' ignored

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `write.table` (CSV stands for *Comma* Seperated Value BTW).

Comment: `write.csv2` defaults to `sep = ";"` (and `dec = ","`, which is why semicolon separators are sometimes used).

Comment: there is no actual specification for what a CSV is. Comma is only the implied delimiter. It needn't be the delimiter used.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First, you should provide a reproducible example.

However, if you use `write.csv2` it defaults to using a semicolon as the separator.

Answer (score 10):

The documentation https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/write.table.html says:

> write.csv uses "." for the decimal point and a comma for the separator.
>
> write.csv2 uses a comma for the decimal point and a semicolon for the separator, the Excel convention for CSV files in some Western European locales.
>
> These wrappers are deliberately inflexible: they are designed to ensure that the correct conventions are used to write a valid file. Attempts to change append, col.names, sep, dec or qmethod are ignored, with a warning.

So it not only defaults to this seperator, it enforces it. Use

```
write.table(data,file="data.csv",sep=",",dec = " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `fwrite`, [fast CSV writer](http://%20https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.11.0/topics/fwrite), with option `sep = ";"`.